# How does an X86 Linux system maintain the system time, when no NTP etc. is in play?

Tags: linux, time, interrupt, clock

When an x86 Linux system is powered up and running, how does it keep track of software time?  E.g. is it incrementing a software counter based on hardware interrupts from the RTC, or is there some internal timer on the x86 chip, or something else entirely?

When I do a cat of /proc/interrupts, interrupt 8 (the RTC interrupt) has only fired once.

Also what could be causing the system time to be running faster on some systems, in a fleet of identical deployed hardware?

Comment: This is described fairly well and much better than I could put in words @ https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/rtc.txt .